# Discrete mathematics Hamming balls reference

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory

Could you name a discrete mathematics  book which discusses Hamming balls and spheres alongside boolean functions and in a deep manner? I'm particularly interested in their combinatorial properties,for example some problems that require counting the number of intersections of Hamming balls with the same distance and different centres. Well,if there are no such discrete mathematics books then at least some coding theory books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The study of such questions is the key to various upper bounds in coding theory. So my suggestion is that you take a book on mathematical coding theory and read the sections on bounds.

Two classical examples are MacWilliams, Sloane: *The Theory of Error-Correcting Codes* and Huffman, Pless: *Fundamentals of Error-Correcting Codes*.